# Simple proof on uniform distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

We have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$. $X$ follows uniform distribution. If $Y = aX + b$, how is any particular **percentile** of the Y distribution related to the corresponding **percentile** of the X distribution?

I know the answer is straight forward: If the value of $m$ has a particular percentile in $X$, the value of $am+b$ has the same percentile in $Y$. However, I just do not know how to prove this.

Comment: Can't you use the fact that  $ F_Y (y) = \{Y< y \} $ then $ F_X (y) = \{ aX+b < y \} = \{ X <(y-b)/a \} $ ?

Comment: I think that the question is to prove $F_Y(am+b) = F_X(m)$, for all $m \in \mattabb{R}$?

Comment: What I gave you should give you enough information,  simply replace y with am+b

Comment: In other words, $ F_Y (y)=\{ Y <y\}=F_X (y)=F_X (m)$

Comment: I am not the brightest in stats. So you mean:
$F_Y(y) = P(Y<y) = P(aX+b<y) = P(X<\frac{y-b}{a}) = F_X(\frac{y-b}{a})$?

Comment: Oh, so the solution is:
$F_X(x) = P(X < x) = P(\frac{Y-b}{a} < x) = P(Y<ax+b) = F_Y(ax+b)$

Comment: Since $Y=aX+b$ then you can say that $ y = am+b $ for all values of the random variable, thus from what we said before, $F_Y(y)=P\{ Y < y \} = P\{aX+b<y \} = P\{X< \frac{y-b}{a} \} = F_X(\frac{y-b}{a})$
Since y=am+b, then $F_X(\frac{y-b}{a})=F_X(m) $ 
Thus you've shown that $F_Y(y)=F_Y(am+b)=F_X(m)$

Comment: Got you! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ the $\alpha$-th percentile of $X$. By definition, we have $P(X\leq m)=\alpha$.

So **if $a>0$**, $\alpha=P(X\leq m)=P(aX+b\leq am+b)=P(Y\leq am+b)$

We have $P(Y\leq am+b)=\alpha$, which means that $am+b$ is the $\alpha$-th percentile of $Y$, by definition.

Comment: So you mean:
$F_X(x) = P(X < x) = P(aX+b < ax+b) = P(Y<ax+b) = F_Y(ax+b)$. Am I right?

Comment: But your method only work if $a \geq 0$? If $a < 0$, then the sign $\leq$ will change?

Comment: Yes, if $a<0$ you have to change the inequality. But then the answer is no longer $am+b$.

Comment: If$a < 0$, then $F_X(m) = P(X < m) = P(aX+b > am+b) = P(Y > am+b)$. And then?

Comment: @Joseph $P(Y>am+b)=1-P(Y\leq am+b)$  So if $m$ is the $\alpha$ percentile of $X$, what is $am+b$ to $Y$?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Search me.

Comment: If $a<0$, as $F_X(m) = P(Y > am+b) = 1-P(Y \leq am+b)$, then $P(Y \leq am+b) = 1 - F_X(m)$

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim\mathcal U(\alpha;\beta)$ then $F_X(x)=\dfrac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha}~\raise{0.25ex}{\chi}_{x\in(\alpha;\beta)}+\raise{0.25ex}{\chi}_{x\in[\beta;\infty)}$

The percentile function is the inverse of the CDF.

$$\begin{align}Q_X(p) = & ~ F_X^{-1}(p/100) \\[1ex] = & ~ \alpha+(\beta-\alpha) p/100\end{align}$$

Since $Y=aX+b$ then $Y\sim\mathcal U(a\alpha+b, a\beta+b)$  (If $a>0$)

$$\begin{align}Q_Y(p) = & ~ F_Y^{-1}(p/100) \\[1ex] = & ~ a\alpha+b+(a\beta+b-a\alpha-b)p/100 \\[1ex] = & ~ b+a(\alpha+(\beta-\alpha)p/100) \\[1ex] = & ~ a~Q_X(p)+b\end{align}$$

Which is as was anticipated.

Can you do $a<0$?